# Running msiexec with PowerShell

Tags: script, powershell, powershell-2.0, batch

I'm try to run `msiexec` in PowerShell but I keep getting an error message. If I run it from `cmd` then it's all fine.

Can someone please let me know how I can run this command in PowerShell?

This is the command I have typed in PowerShell:

```
msiexec.exe /qb /I "C:\m_temp\Floating\PrimeWixInstaller.msi" INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\Mathcad\Mathcad Prime 1.0" ALT_DOC_DIR="C:\Program Files\Mathcad\Mathcad Prime 1.0"
```

When I try to run the command then the Windows Installer help window pops up:

[image: Windows Installer help window]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because the arguments contain spaces (for example, `"C:\Program Files\Mathcad\Mathcad Prime 1.0"`). In such cases you must escape the quotes around the arguments.

The escape character in PowerShell is the grave-accent(`).

So the command should look something like this:

```
msiexec.exe /qb /I "C:\myInstaller.msi" INSTALLLOCATION=`"C:\Program Files\installFolder`" ALT_DOC_DIR=`"C:\Program Files\otherFolder`"
```